# Why can functions with different calling conventions still call each other?

Tags: c++, calling-convention, function-call

```
int __cdecl funcB(int a, int b) {

    return 0;
}

int __stdcall funcA(int a, int b) {

    return funcA(a, b);
}
```

I wrote this two functions and they have different calling conventions: `__stdcall` and `__cdecl`.

And my question is why MSVC didn't throw a compile error?

Because in my view two functions with different calling conventions can't call each other

If caller think callee should clean the stack, and callee think caller should clean the stack, and that's my problem

Any answers will be helpful

Comment: your view is based on what? Why do you expect an error?

Comment: I see no problem, the compiler has all the information it needs to do the right thing. It is not that you are calling funcB as __stdcall.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number If caller think callee should clean the stack, and callee think caller should clean the stack, and that's my problem

Comment: I think you broke your example when retyping it.

Comment: @Suric The function doesn't think anything; it is the compiler that creates the calls, and it (obviously) knows what to do with every convention.

Comment: If your assumption would be right then it would be pointless to specify calling convention per function, because anyhow they would all need to be the same

Comment: Why wouldn't they be able to call each other?    Calling convention for a function specifies to the compiler how that function is called (e.g. how it emits code to call the function correctly, and handles what happens after the called function returns).  That's a different thing from constraining what functions are allowed to call it.

Comment: " caller think callee should clean the stack, and callee think caller should clean the stack," you should add that to the question. Currently from the question it is unclear how you come to the conclusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because in my view two functions with different calling conventions can't call each other

That's simply an incorrect view. A calling convention is just a set of rules for how arguments are handled across the call. The compiler generates instructions at each call site and within the body of the function that follow whichever convention the function is defined with.

> If caller think callee should clean the stack, and callee think caller should clean the stack, and that's my problem

The problem you are thinking of is when the calling convention is omitted, and different translation units are compiled with different default conventions. The declarations in one TU are used in a manner incompatible with the definition in another TU.